# Replace variable value on method call

Tags: ruby, variables, methods

Let's say I have the following class:

```
class MyClass

  @@instances = []
  def initialize
    @@instances << self
  end#def

  def delete
    @@instances.delete(self)
    #what now??
    self.replace nil #doesn't do the trick
  end#def

end#class
```

I would like to do the following:

```
o = MyClass.new
o.delete
```

And `o` will be `nil` on execution of `delete`. Any ideas?

Comment: This is impossible: You can only modify the object itself, not `o` which is a reference to it and which is not accessible from the `delete` method.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get an array of all the instances of `MyClass`, all you need to do is

```
ObjectSpace.each_object(MyClass).to_a
```

If you want to destroy the instance `o` of `MyClass` given that `o` is not referred to anywhere else, then let `o` refer to something else

```
o = nil
```

At some time later, the object will be garbage collected.

Answer (score 0):

As Eureka above points out, this cannot be done. However you can implement similar semantics:

```
class MyClass
  def delete
    ....
    is_deleted
  end

  def is_deleted
     check_some_conditions
  end
end
```

Then, your syntax would be:

```
o = MyClass.new
if o.delete.is_deleted
  ...
end
```

You could also override `nil?` but I do not recommend it, because it might confuse people using your code.

Comment: @user1130886 What do you mean?

Comment: Sorry, just getting used to writing comments on StackOverflow. Thought I was writing an answer instead of a Comment

Answer (score 0):

One possibility might be:

```
vars = Kernel.global_variables + Kernel.local_variables
vars.map{|var| var=nil if var == self}
```

But, I don't think that is a clever one...

EDIT: nope, not clever at all

Comment: Very interesting. However, there's still a reference to that object, even though the Kernel doesn't know about it, that is, in the execution context.